# How can I create this specific view holder using recyclerView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, recyclerview-layout

I want the recyclerView to:

1. enable the user to insert an image to be a background
2. place the user's caption text on the light black ribbon at the bottom image.
3. have the heart on the top right corner of the image, which can be clicked by a user.

Please check the picture to clearly understand... thanks in advance

[image: Here is the image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `constraintLayout`. 
It's so efficient to make a layout what you want.
Using `constraintLayout` you can overlap views.
Check this.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout.html

And than `setOnClickListener` on each `View` in your `ViewHolder`class.

```
static class YourViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

   YourViewHolder(View itemView){
     super(itemView);
  }
```

I hope its can help you.